# CSS mouse-over overlapping tabs?

Tags: html, css, tabs

I've got some tabs.

http://img196.imageshack.us/img196/7167/tabs.gif

And I want to add a rollover effect. Problem is, the tabs overlap each other so there's no nice place to divide them. Should I just use absolute positioning and PNGs to stack them, or is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: Do the tabs have to switch order on click? ie does Friends ever have to come out in front?

Comment: @Ian: No... it'll just turn white where it is. I think changing the order would be a bad UI design decision.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use 24bit PNGs with alpha transparency .. then it shouldn't matter that they overlap. You could position them in a line floated left, with a negative margin left (useful if the tabs are not predetermined), or as you said, you could position them absolutely.

Note, in IE6, alpha trans is not supported. So maybe you'll want to target that browser with no 24 bit transparency images, or try and use the [ie6pngfix](http://www.greyhats.com/2006/11/10/a-better-ie6-png-fix/).

Here is what you *could* do

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="">link1</a></li>
    <li><a href="">link1</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="">link2</a></li>
</ul>

ul li {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin-left: -20px;
    background: url(path/to/image.png) no-repeat;

}

ul li:hover { /* will not work in ie6 - either change the background to the anchor, or add a slice of js */
     background-position: -200px 0; /* i'm using sprites in this example */
}

ul li:first-child {
    margin-left: 0;
}

ul li.active {
    position: relative; /* Mark reminded me I needed to set a position other than static */
    z-index: 100;
}
```

Comment: Very thorough answer! Thank you.

Comment: I aim to please! No worries :)

Comment: Just FYI, z-index only works on position absolute/relative/fixed elements. I had to add "relative" to make it take effect in FF.

Comment: I did think about that when I did the mock up. Glad you got it to work.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to break the tabs up so that the overlap are separate images, then force those images to change depending on which tab is in front.  The Rollover could affect multiple targets.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like:

> #recent a + #friends a:hover {
>
> ```
> background-image: url('recent-normal-neighbor-hover.png') no-repeat;
> ```
>
> }
>
> #friends a:hover {
>
> ```
>  background-image: url('friends-hover-neighbor-normal.png') no-repeat;
> ```
>
> }

Not sure if that even makes sense, and it isn't very elegant, because you'd have to make a regular image for all three tabs, a regular image for all three tabs with the clipped portion of the neighboring tab having a hover state, and a hover image for all three tabs.  Then you'd need to have like 6 CSS selectors.

Comment: Hrm... don't think I've seen this "adjacent sibling" operator. Is it well supported? Do you think the two images would always change in sync? Image-tearing would look pretty bad.

Answer (score 0):

You could use relative positioning to move each tab to the left so it appears over the one before. For this to work correctly you will need to incrementally increase the right position each time eg:

**The HTML**

```
<ul>
   <li id="tab1"><a href="#">Tab1</a></li>
   <li id="tab2"><a href="#">Tab2</a></li>
   <li id="tab3"><a href="#">Tab3</a></li>
   <li id="tab4"><a href="#">Tab4</a></li>
</ul>
```

**The CSS**

```
#tab2 {
   position:relative;
   right:30px; /* overlap distance */
}
#tab3 {
   position:relative;
   right:60px; /* double overlap distance */
}
#tab4 {
   position:relative;
   right:90px; /* triple overlap distance */
}
```

Comment: You're leaving out a few details. <li>s a block-level elements -- each one will appear on a new line. You either need to float it, or inline it. Inlining is producing weird results, and float+right is weird.

Comment: @Mark Yes, you need to make the anchor tags block and both the li and anchor tags should float to the left. If you float the li's to the right you will reverse the order of your tabs.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I went with:

#### HTML

```
<ul id="tabs">
    <li class="upload"><a href="/upload"></a></li>
    <li class="friends"><a href="/friends"></a></li>
    <li class="recent"><a href="/recent"></a></li>
</ul>
```

#### CSS

```
#tabs {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: auto;
    position: absolute;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
}

#tabs li {
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    width: 182px;
    height: 49px;
}

#tabs li a {
    display: block;
    width: 182px;
    height: 49px;
}

#tabs .upload {
    background: transparent url(/img/upload.png) no-repeat top left;
    z-index: 3;
}

#tabs .friends {
    background: transparent url(/img/friends.png) no-repeat top left;
    margin-right: -34px;
    z-index: 2;
}

#tabs .recent {
    background: transparent url(/img/recent.png) no-repeat top left;
    margin-right: -31px;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: Nvm...this doens't work nice in IE8 when I add links...*sigh*